# I want to redirect globital.media.com to globital.media

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web, extension-methods

Is there any possible solution for doing this type of practice. Actually, we miss printed our business cards with the wrong web address.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it through either on .htaccess or on the php files of

> globital.media.com

but first you need to purchase another domain where your web files reside which is the

> globital.media

Basically you can change the a records on globital.media.com with the ip of globital.media.